# TFS Command-line Crashing

Tags: command-line, tfs, crash

I'm trying to set up a build script involving code checked into TFS 2010.  Everything works fine from the IDE, but the command-line functions crash every time I try to access it.  Specifically, "tf workspace" and "tf workspaces" work just fine, but "tf history," "tf get," and anything else that might be useful create an unhandled exception.  No matter how I format these commands, the program still crashes.  I have looked everywhere on the Internet for a key to this problem, to no avail.  This is driving me nuts.  Here is a sample, run from a "Visual Studio Command Prompt:"

```
tf history * /version:T
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.DialogHistory.set_Workspace(Workspace value)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.CommandLine.CommandHistory.Run()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.CommandLine.VersionControlCommandLine.RunCommand(String commandName, String[] args, Boolean& showExitCode)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.CommandLine.RunCommand(String[] args)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.CommandLine.Run(String[]& args)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.CommandLine.VersionControlCommandLine.Main(String[] args)
```

I apologize if the use of the command is totally wrong, but given that everything I put in makes it crash, I have no frame of reference.

UPDATE:

[I originally posted this comment, but it was deleted as the moderator felt it was more of an "update" than an answer.]

Thank you all for the tips. The day I posted this our TFS server crashed and had to be re-created. I didn't change any of the code or workspaces. When our IT guy recreated it, everything worked perfectly. I have tried to find some difference between the old and new server for the sake of posterity, but I have not found anything.

Comment: Looks as if the script is running outside of any workspace. But normally, that would result in a `Unable to determine workspace` error, so that you get an exception seems strange.

Comment: Run `tf workspaces` to verify you have a valid workspace. If you don't, you need to create it first.

Comment: Are you running visual studio in admin mode? If you run the command prompt using a normal user account you won't be able to set the workspace properly.  If that's the case try running the command from an elevated commend prompt.
I assume you are running the commands from a folder that is mapped to a workspace?